# How and when did the penal substitutionary view become popular? How popular today is it?

Tags: atonement, penal-substitution

It seems very popular among evangelicals today, is it the main theory? Do other Christians generally support this view, and have they supported it historically? Does it have historical support in the first centuries of the first church fathers?

Comment: There is no solid support prior to the first millennium, at least in any See other than the Roman. It is based largely the work of the Roman Catholic theologian, Anselm of Canterbury, expressed in [Cur Deus Homo](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Cur_Deus_Homo).

Comment: This question has a few too many questions in it. If it asked which Christians currently hold to penal substitution, that *might* be answerable here. Whether it has historical support in early Christianity is another question entirely—and a highly debated one between Protestants, who often claim it *is* supported in writings of the early church Fathers, and the rest of Christianity, especially the Catholic and Orthodox, who make very cogent arguments to the effect that it is *not* supported in the early church Fathers.

Comment: The two questions are closely enough related I think it is okay to ask them together.